# Find Skype presence in EWS

Tags: exchangewebservices, skype-for-business

Is it possible to retrieve a users Skype for Business (Server) presence through EWS (on-prem), possibly if the Unified Contact Store is enabled? If so, where exactly can I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No EWS doesn't provide any interfaces for Sykpe (or Teams) you need to use one of the Skype API's usually UCWA API is the easiest way to do this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucwa/getpresencedataofacontact